# Script fails in WinPython, attempting to import lapack_til

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to run a script my client has provided, but I can't get it to start; it seems certainly a setup question on my machine, as it works for them. I started by installing WinPython from http://scipy.org/, but I'm now getting the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyconsole.py", line 18, in <module>
    import cocomo
  File "pyconsole\cocomo.py", line 13, in <module>
    import grupple
  File "pyconsole\grupple.py", line 4, in <module>
    import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
  File "C:\Users\lab\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from matplotlib.rcsetup import (defaultParams,
  File "C:\Users\lab\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 19, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import is_color_like
  File "C:\Users\lab\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 52, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\lab\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\lab\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\lab\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from polynomial import *
  File "C:\Users\lab\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py", line 17, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq, inv
  File "C:\Users\lab\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\linalg\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from linalg import *
  File "C:\Users\lab\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 23, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I'm not confident in interpreting Python tracebacks, but it seems that "lapack_lite" is missing?  Searching around a bit seems surprisingly unhelpful; the best I've seemed to determine is that it is part of numpy?  But that's odd, as the reason I started with the WinPython distribution is that the numpy stack is pre-installed, and that is the easiest way to get started with that.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Your WinPython is Python27? 32 bit or 64bit? WinPython usually does not install Python in ApData. I suspect that you are still using old python you had before WinPython.

Answer (score 0):

i think the easiest way under Windows would be to simply install Anaconda (this takes care of all the dependencies of Numpy and Scipy). You can download it from here:

https://www.continuum.io/downloads

This way you dont have to scroll through pages of Documentation on how to get all dependencies right.

Kind regards

Johann